# Check which sub-domain is view often

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site where in I have a subdomain for every user. Though it is the same page for every user but the data varies according to the subdomain ie for every particular user. Currently I have google analytics code giving me data for number of subdomains page visit (not for any particular user). Is there a way I could get data for every particular user's subdomain page visit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically yes - set a custom variable with the user name and create segments (or use filters), or use virtual urls that include the user's name.

Legally, no. Using personal identifiable data is a violation of Googles terms of service and and in many countries a violation of privacy laws as well. You might go for a coded id per user but even that seem's flaky (since it would be possible to map the id to a user).